# The data type of the column 'AddressLine1' in the external table is different than the column's data type

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

The error message:
The data type of the column 'AddressLine1' in the external table is different than the column's data type in the underlying standalone or sharded table present on the external source.

Is displayed when i try and query an external data table in Azure SQL. The data table is:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ExternalTable
(
[LastName] nvarchar (255)
,[FirstName] nvarchar (255)
,[AddressLine1] varchar(max)
) WITH (DATA_SOURCE = Externaldb)
```

The underlying data on the db is from a view not from the source table. This is what is causing my problem. The AddressLine1 field in the view is actually:

```
REPLACE((ISNULL([AddressLine1],'')),',',' ') as [AddressLine1]
```

rather than the original data.

I have tried the following data types in the create external table script but none of them work:

```
nvarchar(255)
nvarchar(max)
varchar(255)
varchar(max)
```

I do not know how to find the data type that Azure SQL is assigning to this column in the view.

Comment: Can you explicitly cast that in the view? `CAST(REPLACE((ISNULL([AddressLine1],'')),',',' ')  AS VARCHAR(255)) as [AddressLine1]`?

Comment: I can! And that's fixed it. Thanks very much JNevill. Awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Billson3000, you can think about  mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thanks for JNevill again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @JNevill's answer in comment, it helped @Billson3000 fix it:

Cast the AddressLine1 field in the view in the view:

```
CAST(REPLACE((ISNULL([AddressLine1],'')),',',' ') AS VARCHAR(255)) as [AddressLine1]
```

This fixed the issue.

I help them post it as answer, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Thanks @JNevill again.

Comment: Thanks Leon Yue. I will do that next time. I didn't know I could do that. Thanks for all your help.